# Magento robots.txt rule also blocking JavaScript from WordPress

Tags: robots.txt, magento

I have a Magento site and a WordPress site is used in a directory for the blog. My blog keeps getting hit as not mobile friendly and the reason I believe is that there are certain resources blocked in *robots.txt*. The part of my *robots.txt* that is giving me problems is this:

```
# Do not index session ID     
Disallow: /*?SID=     
Disallow: /*?     
Disallow: /*.php$
```

This is from the standard Magento template. One of the blocked resource URL is: `https://www.example.com/blog/wp-content/plugins/megamenu/js/maxmegamenu.js?ver=2.6`

I think this line `Disallow: /*?`  is blocking that example URL. I would prefer not to remove that line. Is there a way to allow everything in the wp-content directory while still blocking the Magento URLs with that rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understood is that you have a Magento website on https://www.example.com and a Wordpress website on https://www.example.com/blog
You want to keep `Disallow: /*?` but at the same time allow the files with this pattern to be crawled in your Wordpress website under `/blog`

Your robots.txt should be like this

```
# Do not index session ID     
Disallow: /*?SID=     
Disallow: /*?     
Disallow: /*.php$
Allow: /blog/*?
```

Consider testing your robots.txt in the old version of Google Webmasters under **Crawl -> robots.txt Tester**

Comment: Thank you I will give that a try. Does it matter if the allow is before or after the disallow? I am trying to figure out precedence.

Comment: In terms of Google, the order of precedence does not matter